# How do I get my arrow keys working in the at> prompt

Tags: shell, terminal, at

Whenever I try to use the arrow keys in the `at>` prompt (after, for example, running `at now`) it just shows control codes, eg. `^[[D` for <kbd>←</kbd>.

This makes pasting and editing long commands difficult as the only viable option is to edit, copy and paste from a separate document.

So, how do I get arrow keys to work in the `at>` prompt?

(Googling for anything having to do with the `at>` prompt or `/usr/bin/at` is quite difficult…)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a program such as [rlwrap](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap) (readline wrapper) for this:

```
rlwrap at now
```

Further reading:

- [hanslub42/rlwrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) (github)

  ```
  * HOW TO USE IT:
  If 

    $ <command> <args>

  doesn't let you use arrow keys to edit input, or if you just want
  decent input history and completion, try:

    $ rlwrap [-options] <command> <args>
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
at now << EOF
  commands
     ︙
EOF
```

You'll be able to do readline-like editing while you're typing the commands.

Answer (score 1):

[Hans Lub's `rlwrap`](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) is one such tool for doing this.  It employs the GNU Readline library.

It was written in 1999, the same year that Per Bothner wrote `rlfe`, a similar tool that is now bundled with GNU Readline as an example program.  Debian builds the example, tacks on [a Debian-only manual page](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/rlfe/rlfe.1.en.html) and packages them in [the rlfe package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/rlfe).

GNU Readline is not the only line editing library around.  But I do not know of any similar wrapper tools that employ editline/libedit.

Of course, if you are using the "here document" idea from another answer, you may well be using another editing library.  If your shell is the Z shell you will be editing the "here document" using ZLE, for example.